# if an option "ALL" is selected, how do I make sure other options does not run?

Tags: java, user-interface

so here's my question... I am using java eclipse. I have this few options designed to allow the user to tick in the checkbox of the java GUI. But I have this one option that is "All", how can I ensure that when the "All" option is ticked, the other options that is ticked will not run except for this "All" option?

What can I do to solve this problem??

Here's my java coding..

```
btnStart.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent args)
        {
            //if checkbox_4 (ALL) is being selected, the other checkboxes will be disabled/not running so there will not be overlapping..
            if(checkbox_4.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {   
                    String command = "cmd /c start /wait "+DetectDrive+"\\All.bat";
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    p.waitFor();
                } 
                catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if(checkbox.isSelected())
            {
                try
                {   
                    String command = "cmd /c start /wait "+DetectDrive+"\\1.bat";
                    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
                    p.waitFor();
                } 
                catch (IOException | InterruptedException e1)
                {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }

            //so on and so forth..
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should do that in the UI. The user should get the clear idea that selecting "ALL" overrides all other options (for example, disabling them). And of course, nothing stops you from doing  a `return` and performing the logic for "ALL".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `IF ELSE` statement.

if the checkbox_4 is selected, then run it. else check if other boxes are ticked, if yes. run it. short and simple.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setEnabled(false)` on all the other checkboxes.

Be sure to re-enable them once the "all" checkbox is unselected.